# .htaccess https to http redirect conflict with existing rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

Currently we have this rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on <br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site/index [L]
```

What this does is for any visit we will redirect to subfolder call site if the page not found.  And when this happen the url will not show site as subfolder.
Example if we have
/rootFolder/site/temp.html this will show in url as

http://www.domain.com/temp.html

This is working fine but now we need to add https redirect if user visit site.

This is the new rule I came up with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/site/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/site/index [L]
```

But the issue with this one is now url will show site subfolder
https://www.domain.com/site/temp.html

How can I achieve so that if user does

http://www.domain.com/temp.html  it will find temp.html in site subfolder and redirect to https and url will only show

https://www.domain.com/temp.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you do it in two passes, always redirecting whatever was requested to https, then running your rewrite rules, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#301 flag redirects instead of rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#leaving your original rules as is
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site/index [L]
```

Comment: that was the first thing i tried and it does not work.  Weird this is it does work on my mac but does not work with apache on AWS.  Here is the rule

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site/index [L]

Comment: according to the Network trace on chrome it trigger 301 https redirect but the second block doesn't get invoke.  So the https doesn't response (take too long to respond)

Comment: It worked. I checked again and it worked. The reason why it did not work earlier because of AWS block on 443.  Many thanks